# How to take more than two in logical quantifiers

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Let the universe of discourse be all humans. Let $F(x,y)$ denote $x$ is a friend of $y$.

Stating the following logically: No one has more than two friends.

$$ \neg ( \exists x \exists y \exists z((Fx \land Fx) \land (Fy \land Fy)) \land (Fz \land Fz)) \land (x \neq y) \land (y \neq z) \land (x \neq z))$$

Is the above statement I derived correct? I used some other answer to mash this one up, could you explain each part of this statement if correct please?

Comment: Your predicate $F(x,y)$ takes two arguments, so I'm not really sure what $Fx$, $Fy$, or $Fz$ is supposed to mean...

Comment: I thought I could add $z$ to my argument since the universe of discourse is all humans. There was a sample question where it showed "At most two" where the discourse was all humans, so I believed I could add $z$, i guess thats incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression clearly cannot be right, because the relation $F$ takes two arguments, and in your expression you’ve given it only one. Let’s start over from scratch. First we write a logical expression $\varphi(x)$ that says ‘$x$ has more than two friends’; once we have that, the desired sentence will be $\forall x\big(\neg\varphi(x)\big)$ or, equivalently, $\neg\exists x\big(\varphi(x)\big)$.

To say that $x$ has more than two friends is to say that $x$ has at least three friends; that means that there are $y_1,y_2$, and $y_3$ such that $x$ is a friend of each of them, and no two of them are the same person. It’s easy to say that $x$ is a friend of $y_1$: that’s just $F(x,y_1)$. To say that $x$ is a friend of each of the three is therefore

$$F(x,y_1)\land F(x,y_2)\land F(x,y_3)\;.$$

We also have to specify that $y_1,y_2$, and $y_3$ are three different people:

$$y_1\ne y_2\land y_1\ne y_3\land y_2\ne y_3\;.$$

A formula $\varphi(x)$ that says ‘$x$ has more than two friends’ is therefore

$$\exists y_1\exists y_2\exists y_3\Big(F(x,y_1)\land F(x,y_2)\land F(x,y_3)\land y_1\ne y_2\land y_1\ne y_3\land y_2\ne y_3\Big)\;.$$

Comment: I see that $y$ is denoting each friend of $x$. Although this denotes at more than two friends, which means over three friends will the following equation mean `No one has more than TWO friends?` If I negate your equation, would it read that?

Comment: @GivenPie: There actually is no $y$ in any of the expressions: there are three different variables $y_1,y_2$, and $y_3$. If you wish, you could replace them by $y,z$, and $w$, for instance. No, negating my last line does *not* give you something saying that no one has more than two friends. (It doesn’t even give you a statement, because it still contains the free variable $x$.) To say that no one has more than three friends you should use one of the expressions that I mentioned at the end of the first paragraph; the second one, $\neg\exists x\big(\varphi(x)\big)$ is probably the more natural.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it in words, but if you like symbols:
$$\forall x,a,b,c \ (F(x,a) \wedge F(x,b) \wedge F(x,c)) \implies (a = b \vee a = c \vee b = c)$$
or, perhaps more readable:
$$\forall x \ |\{y : F(x,y)\}| \le 2$$